# Two inputs before the if statement

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

For the following code I have to put 2 inputs before I get to the ifstatement. Java is quiet new for me so I don't understand what I did wrong. Can anyone help me with solving this problem?

```
package oefenen;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class oefenen {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        String name;
        System.out.println("Adin ne?");
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        name = scan.next();

            if (scan.next().equals("samet")); {
                System.out.println("Merhaba memetin oglu");
            }

    }

}
```

Comment: `name.equals("samet")` instead of `scan.next().equals("samet")`. `scan.next()` actually scans the next token from the inputstream. If you need to compare name you need to use the variable in which the name is stored.

Comment: `nextLine()`. The first `next()` does not consume the `\n`, so this is consumed by the next one.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve ? This code does take 2 inputs, although you don't use the first input

Comment: @ChandlerBing Im not trying to achieve anything. I'm just playing with code to understand the basics from java.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You ignore the value of `name`

And your if statement is actually being ignored as well due to the semicolon at the end

Try this

```
 if (name.equals("samet")) { // remove semicolon
```

Answer (score 2):

`scan.next()` will wait for new input each time you call it.

Try using `name.equals("samet")` instead of `scan.next().equals("samet")`

Comment: Answers all the problems but it would be helpful to also explain in deep what is going on, I think that is what OP struggles with the most.

Answer (score 0):

From the Scanner.next() doc :

> Finds and returns the next complete token from this scanner.
>   A complete token is preceded and followed by input that matches
>   the delimiter pattern. This method may block while waiting for input
>   to scan, even if a previous invocation of  `hasNext` returned 
>   `true`.

Every time you call `next()` method, it tries to read an input, in your example you called the method twice that's why you have to enter two inputs before you get to your print statement